# How do two atomic formulas unify?

Tags: prolog, unification

I have learned `loves(bob,Y) and loves(X,santa)` can unify because `{Y\santa,X\bob}`. However, I'm not sure if the following can be unified:

```
m(a,X) and n(Y,b)
```

Comment: You could also just try at the REPL: `?- m(a, X) = n(Y, b).`

Answer (score 1):

In order for unification the functors must match exactly. That is m and n are two different functors hence the entire expression cannot unify. In the first example the functors for both expressions are the same.

Comment: I thought that two different functions could also unify. Now I understand. Thank you,Vincent.

Comment: @Stella in Prolog, they are not *functions* but *functors*. They do not behave as *functions* as in other languages. A *functor* is a named structure containing other terms (variables, functors, atoms).